# Запятая в конструкции "Чтобы [условие] (запятая) [результат]"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Чтобы вернуться в Finder с помощью клавиатуры, нажми Command-Tab.

В английском языке запятая здесь обычно ставится. А в русском?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В русском языке запятая в таком предложении ставится в **обязательном** порядке: ***Чтобы вернуться** в Finder с помощью клавиатуры, **нажми** Command-Tab.*

**Пояснение**

Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с придаточным **цели** (союз ***ЧТОБЫ***).

Придаточное предложение **в препозиции.** Такие предложения выражают **взаимообусловленные** отношения.

**Главное** предложение: ***нажми** Command-Tab.*

Это односоставное определенно-личное предложение, сказуемое выражено глаголом ***нажми*** в форме повелительного наклонения.

**Придаточное** предложение: ***Чтобы вернуться** в Finder с помощью клавиатуры.*

Это односоставное инфинитивное предложение, сказуемое выражено глаголом ***вернуться*** в форме инфинитива.